# SAS behavior of intck

Tags: sas

In SAS, is there a difference between the two:

```
a =intck('month',start_dt - 1, end_dt);
```

and

```
a =intck('month',start_dt, end_dt);
```

Does subtracting the 1 day from start_dt make any difference in any circumstances?

Comment: So what tests did you run?

Answer (score 3):

It will result in different output if the start_dt is the first of the month. Because start_dt - 1 will fall in previous month and will add '1' to the result of intck.

Comment: No necessarily, if the start date lets say 2nd of the month, then it would only move the date back to 1st of the month. Start date and end date would still be in the same month and wouldn't make any difference.